# How to add between in query builder?

Tags: php, yii2

I am implementing a custom search, and now I need to select values in range for `date` column.

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Books::find();
    //.....
    
    $timestampStart = strtotime($this->dateStart),
    $timestampEnd = strtotime($this->dateEnd)
    
    // How to add BETWEEN here?!!?!
    $query->andBetween('date', $timestampStart, $timestampEnd) // pseudo-code
```

From the documentation, it's not entirely clear how to use that:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md

Comment: `['between', 'date', $timestampStart, $timestampEnd]`

Comment: @RobertRozas Yes I see, but how to apply `['between', 'i', 1, 10]` to `$query` object?

Comment: Try `$query->where(['between', 'date', $timestampStart, $timestampEnd]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail), you can use a `where` method call for this.

> between: operand 1 should be the column name, and operand 2 and 3 should be the starting and ending values of the range that the column
>   is in. For example, ['between', 'id', 1, 10] will generate id BETWEEN
>   1 AND 10.

So, in your case, it would look something like:

```
$query->where(['between', 'date', $timestampStart, $timestampEnd]);
```

For more information on building queries, you can also see [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html).